# Not including empty cells in mean calculation in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I am reading a table of values from an excel file as a pandas dataframe, where some cells are empty, as there are some data missing. I need to calculate the mean value of each row, but the empty cells are read as zeros, and so are included in the calculation, which is misleading. How can I calculate the mean value without including the empty cells? I found that the empty cells can be read as 'Nan' only when the table is read as a table of strings, but I need numbers. Any help?

Thanx!

Comment: you want empty cells to be replaced bt `zero (0)`  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any NaN values shouldn't be counted towards the mean. Try replacing whatever your missing values are with `np.nan` and then repeat your mean calculation. If they are currently zeros, try:

```
df.replace(0.0, np.nan, inplace=True)
df.mean()
```

Comment: @ Sean , nice solution. +1

Comment: This is how I thought of solving it at first, but then I thought it was kind of "cheating". Right now there is no way that a cell in the initial table should have a zero value, so each zero in the dataframe is nan, thus your solution can solve the current problem. Do you have any ideas of what I should do when the initial table has actual zero values AND empty cells as well?

Comment: @gtroupis, look at the `df[~pd.isnull(df)] ` if that's useful for your next use case.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can replace empty cells with zeros..

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=['2', 'hello'], B=['', '3']))
>>> df
       A  B
0      2
1  hello  3
>>> def convert_fill(df):
...     return df.stack().apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore').fillna(0).unstack()
...
>>> convert_fill(df)
       A  B
0      2  0
1  hello  3
```

df[~pd.isnull(df)] really been great , it only get non empty cells.

```
>>> print(df[~pd.isnull(df)])
       A  B
0      2
1  hello  3
```